# Picasso Not Loading Images From Server

Tags: android, picasso

My problem statement is to load the images from the server.
Now I have used picasso inside the custom adapter.
The image which I am downloading its size is approximately 100kb 
not more than that.But instead of displaying the image white background is 
been displayed.
To check error I have used callback but somehow the callback is not working
I mean the callback is never getting called.

Below is my code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FolderListAdapter.Viewholder holder, int position) {
    userDetails=userList.get(position);
    //Context context=);
    if(userDetails.getLogo()!=null && !userDetails.getLogo().isEmpty()) {
        Context context=holder.cardProfilePic.getContext();
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(userDetails.getLogo())
                .fit()
                .into(holder.cardProfilePic, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d("succes","success");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                       Log.d("failure","failure");
                    }
                });
    }
    if(userDetails.getBanner()!=null && !userDetails.getBanner().isEmpty()) {
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(userDetails.getBanner())
                 .resize(300,300)
                .into(holder.cardBackgroundPic);
    }
    if(userDetails.getPersonName()!=null && !userDetails.getPersonName().isEmpty()) {
        holder.username.setText(userDetails.getPersonName());
    }
    if(userDetails.getDesignation()!=null && !userDetails.getDesignation().isEmpty()) {
        holder.userRole.setText(userDetails.getDesignation());
    }
}
```

Comment: try passing the activity context through the constructor of you adapter, and use this context in your Picasso.

Comment: Pass activity reference in Picasso with function. Follow this tutorial :- http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/picasso-image-loading-library-for-android-tutorial/ . It may help you.

Comment: I have passed context in the constructor but no help.

Comment: I have tried activity context and activity reference but nothing worked for me.The screen is not displaying image not even error image or placeholder.

Comment: i had also some issues with Picasso Library, then I tried Glide library (Which is recommended by google) , my issues were resolved.
follow this URL https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started

Comment: but before that i need to be sure that the picasso is the root cause and not my code.Can we check whether the image is downloading or not using adb pull do you have any idea